# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) but I have a password in place

Tags: debian, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been trying to install phpmyadmin on my Debian 9 (stretch) system, I already have apache, php and mysql installed and working. When I run

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

it downloads but the installation throws this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

even though I know I have a password for mysql. Is there a way I can force phpmyadmin to use a password when logging into mysql??

Answer (score 1):

Configure/create a `/root/.my.cnf` file and put the following contents:

```
[client]
user=root
password=yourPasswordHere
```

Then re-run the installation process. The issue is that phpmyadmin is attempting to log in to your mysql server and you have not provided a username/password to the phpmyadmin install script. Check the PMA documentation on where to configure this in PMA's config file.